# To find $a,b,c$ as the directional derivative of $f(x,y,z)=axy^2+byz+cz^2x^3$ , at $(1,2-1)$ , is atmost $64$ in a direction parallel to $z$-axis?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

How to find $a,b,c$ such that the directional derivative of $f(x,y,z)=axy^2+byz+cz^2x^3$ , at $(1,2-1)$ , has a maximum value of $64$ in a direction parallel to $z$-axis ? I think I have to equate $\nabla f(1,2,-1) . (1,2,\alpha)=64\sqrt{1^2+2^2+\alpha^2}$ , but I am not sure and I don't even know how to proceed from here even if it is correct . Please help . Thanks in advance .

Comment: A direction (unit vector) parallel to the z-axis is (0,0,1), not (1,2,$\alpha$). Be careful not to confuse directions and position vectors.

Comment: @MattDickau : Parallel to the $z$-axis , not exactly on $z$-axis ..

Comment: $\mathbf r(\alpha) = (1,2,\alpha)$ parameterizes the *position* vectors of a line parallel to the $z$-axis, but the *direction* parallel to the $z$-axis is a vector which is pointed along this line. That is, the head and tail are both on the line, so the direction $\mathbf d = (1,2,\alpha_2) - (1,2,\alpha_1) = (0,0,\alpha_2 - \alpha_1)$. Then, since it is the direction and not magnitude that we care about, we just normalize it to get $(0,0,1)$ or $(0,0,-1)$ depending on whether it points up or down.

Answer (score 4):

$\nabla f=\big(ay^2+3cx^2z^2\big)\hat{i}+\big(2axy+bz\big)\hat{j}+\big(by+2cx^3z\big)\hat{k}$ so that
$$\nabla f(1,2,-1)=(4a+3c)\hat{i}+(4a-b)\hat{j}+(2b-2c)\hat{k}.$$
The directional derivative of $f$ in a direction parallel to $z$-axis, that is, $\hat{k}$ is 
$$\nabla f(1,2,-1)\cdot\hat{k}=(4a+3c)\cdot0+(4a-b)\cdot0+(2b-2c)\cdot1.$$

Since this directional derivative has magnitude at most $64$, we must have

$$4a+3c=0,\qquad 4a-b=0\qquad\text{and}\qquad 2b-2c=64.$$
Solving these equations, we get $a=6$, $b=24$ and $c=-8$.

Answer (score 1):

The directional derivative in the z-direction is just $\partial f/\partial z$ (or in the opposite direction, which would just be the negative of that). So you just need to compute that, evaluate it at the desired point, and find the conditions on the constants which ensure it is less than 64.

Answer (score 0):

Find grad of $f$ and put $(1,2,-1)$ in it.
You will get $(4a+3c) i +(4a-b)j +(2b-2c)k$.
Since parallel to $y$ axis,
$4a+3c=0$ and $2b-2c=0$, From here we get $b=c=-4a/3$.
Put the value of $b$ in $4a-b=64$ as given in question, and
you will get $a=12, b=c=-16$. The answer will be $-20$.